# WAMP - running php file through localhost working fine giving FATAL error while running through batch

Tags: php, batch-file, wamp, oracle-call-interface

I have WAMP installed on my PC, I have my project placed inside 
`C:/WAMP/WWW/MY_PROJECT_NAME/`

I have placed PHP file `sendmail.php` in `C:/WAMP/WWW/MY_PROJECT_NAME/` directory
When i am running these file through browser `http://localhost/MY_PROJECT_NAME/sendmail.php` it working fine, Mails are sending as expected.

I have created batch file to run same php file `sendmail.php`, code of my batch file is as below

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe" -f "C:\wamp\www\MY_PROJECT_NAME\sendmail.php
```

My problem is when I am executing same php file with batch, it is giving me fatal error

> call to undefined function oci_connect()

Can any one help why `fatal error` is showing while executing php script through batch ?

Comment: FYI - my os is Window server 2008, wamp sever version 2.5

Comment: The php on the http server and php in CLI (‘batch’) may use different config files (php.ini).

Comment: I have installed Xampp on separate PC, When i put my project folder in xampp/httdocs/ it is working fine under both cases in browser and through batch......no errors...

Comment: Did you check if the extension is enabled in CLI? 'php.exe --ini' and see which ini file is used in CLI mode.

Comment: Where to run it ? show exact command, i run commnad "--ini" it shows nothing

Comment: Compare the output of `php --ini` at the command line with the output of `phpinfo()` in a web page. You'll probably find different INI files are being used.

Answer (score 0):

The `php.ini` file used by PHP CLI is in

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
```

the `php.ini` file used by Apache is

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{versionnumber}\php.ini
```

make sure you have added/uncommented the `oci` extension to the PHP CLI `php.ini file as well as the Apache version.